# Service fabric cluster takes forever to deploy

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-service-fabric, continuous-deployment, azure-resource-manager

Is there a way to shorten the process? Should I have two service fabric clusters if we want to implement continuous delivery process ?

Comment: how are you deploying? how can we reproduce?

Comment: also how long is forever? :)

Comment: Deploying new changes to the cluster shouldn't bring the cluster down?

Answer (score 1):

If the Service Fabric cluster deployment (i.e. creation of a Service Fabric cluster) is stuck - open an issue in the Azure Portal with support to help get it resolved.

For application deployment you don't need separate cluster to do CD. Depending on your CD strategy (e.g. rolling upgrades, rip and replace, blue/green), there are various ways of doing that in Service Fabric. Take a look here for some of the conceptual documentation on this topic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-upgrade

Comment: We want blue/green deployments to have piece in the mind. Service fabric is great but even seen from the picture it has complex upgrade mechanics. We would like to create the resources. deploy them, Test them  and swap the network traffic to new.

Comment: Ok - you can run parallel versions of application in Service Fabric. When you upload an Application Package it gets registered in the cluster. You can then choose to either update existing application instances, or create a new one based on the new version. If you do this approach, you'll have to handle network traffic routing yourself and also stateful services data cannot be migrated between the instances. However, if you do rolled upgrades, you can control the speed at which upgrades are rolled out and manually move the upgrade forward.

Comment: I am reading pets versus cattle. Where SF looks like a pet if I persist on re-using it.https://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/03/18/servers_pets_or_cattle_cern/

Comment: An SF cluster could be either. It's not a matter of how you decide to use it.